# Why can't I add an answer to my own supposedly "non-constructive" question?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578937/is-there-any-way-to-use-java-without-using-classes

I found several technical, perfect answers to my question after a long search of my own. Yet the question is closed for being "non-constructive".

Is there a way in which I can answer my own question?

Comment: There is a reason that questions that shouldn't be answered are closed so that they cannot be answered

Comment: It is non constructive because it is asking for cement to act like custard and still be  called cement and still expects it to bind like cement.

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot answer a closed question by any means in its current state.

The question was closed as it was not in the kind of question SO allows. And it was not constructive, as well.

Read about what is considered to be on topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

If you still think your question was not off topic, I would suggest following steps:

1. Edit your question in a way other users gets a clear idea of your question.
2. The closed question can be reopened if it is proper after edit.
3. Then you can go and answer your question.

Comment: but it's not off topic nor non-constructive. It's a technical question about a specific software programming problem with a specific singular answer. Is everyone going crazy here? And I already edited it.

Comment: I notice the question is reopened. Go ahead and answer :) @Blub

Comment: I did, seems like it's not considered helpful. I guess believing that it's impossible is a preferable alternative to many people.

Answer (score 1):

As you've learnt, you can't answer a closed question.

However in this case asking about the question on Meta StackOverflow seems to have provided enough interest to get it reopened :-)